# Eliminar y/o actualizar datos masivamente

Tags: php, mysql

Como puedo eliminar datos masivamente de mi base de datos (dado que requiero eliminar mas de 10 mil datos que estan almacenados, y pues eliminar los datos uno por uno no sería lo adecuado)

**Consulta Básica**

```
$deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona 
                  WHERE id_persona = '$id_persona'"
```

Se deben de eliminar los datos que tengan tipo de usuario "Visitante = 4", que tengan un rango de fecha.

```
SELECT * FROM `persona` WHERE id_tipoUsuario = '4'
```

Comment: No pongas un Where y se eliminan

Comment: la pregunta cual es??? si sacando el where anda?? si la pregunta es esa, deberia ser eliminada antes que afecte a mas usuarios con respuestas desastrosas.

Comment: tal parece que no le importan los registros

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que aclarar la pregunta para evitar respuestas que no te sean útil. Por ejemplo, cuando dices que *de forma manual no seria lo ideal*, me imagino que lo que quieres decir es que no quieres eliminar los registros uno a la vez. También aclara cual es el criterio para eliminar los 10.000 registros. Y esos 10.000 registros, ¿qué porcentaje son del total de registros en la tabla?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Comment: @gbianchi espero haber sido mas claro con lo especificado, en la nueva edicion de la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: pero y la pregunta cual es??? si estas poniendo vos mismo la solucion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analiza tu universo de información, en el que debes encontrar un campo en particular que compartan los registros entre si; por ejemplo:
Se desean eliminar los registros de las personas del departamento 'Área de carga'.

```
$deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona 
              WHERE departamento = 'Área de carga'"
```

O bien combinarlos con otra condición, cuando la persona sea del 'Área de carga' y su edad sea mayor o igual a '22'

```
$deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona 
              WHERE departamento = 'Área de carga' AND edad >= '22'"
```

Comment: Bienvenido Angel!! gracias por la respuesta. Mira por favor [tour] para saber como funcionamos.. Si estas siguiendo la pregunta, no esta nada claro lo que quiere quien pregunto, y aunque tu respuesta es correcta, estas suponiendo que es lo que quiere. La proxima vez espera a que el usuario sea claro con lo que quiere, antes de responder.

Answer (score -2):

Pues tienes varias opciones dependiendo de cual se ajuste mejor a tu problema por ejemplo:

```
while($id_persona)
    $deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona 
                      WHERE id_persona = '$id_persona[$i]'"
                      $i++
```

Donde deberías de recorrer el arreglo donde tengas los id de persona de los que deseas eliminar.

Si quieres borrar todo sería suficiente con:

```
    $deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona"
```

Otra opción es que concatenes todos los id separados por comas:

```
    $deletePersona = "DELETE FROM persona 
                      WHERE id_persona IN (5,6,8,9,...)"
```